# FCM notification payload - determine topic name when app is not running

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

Backend server sends FCM notification like this:

```
{
  "to": "/topics/599_7041",
  "priority": "high",
  "data": {
    "id_message": "45" 
  }
  "click_action": "SHOW" 
  "notification" : {
      "body" : "Lorem ipsum",
      "title" : "Sample" 
    }
}
```

My application subscribes multiple topics. When application is not running, Firebase displays notification and allows me to run app after tap on notification message, with provided click action and pass data (in this case, `message_id`) to launched app instance.

Good so far. However, in addition, I need to determine from which subscribed topic notification is received. Can I determine it somehow when launching new app instance from notification, or I need to add topic name to data (next to `message_id`)?

I know I can determine `to` filed when my app is running, this way:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull final RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
{
 //....
 String to = remoteMessage.getTo();
}
```

But, what if my app is not running, so `onMessageReceived` won't be called.

Comment: You can try to use lifespan of a message. More information you can find [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

Comment: How lifespan is related to my question?

Comment: how are u sending topic messages from console?

Comment: Look at my question, message body is included (json)

Comment: add the topic name in the message title

Comment: I can add topic name in `data` and pass it the same way as `message_id`, as I mentioned. It seems to be dumb solution though, this is why I asked here.

Comment: thats the only solution

Comment: You need to use a data-only message payload in order to handle the notifications on your own.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
exports.pushNotification =
functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}').onWrite( event => {

console.log('Push notification event triggered');


var valueObject = event.data.val();

console.log("it is"+ valueObject.title);
//Create a notification
const payload = {
 notification: {
    title:valueObject.title,
    body: valueObject.message,
    sound: "default"
},
};
```

This way you are using the database trigger `onWrite`, that checks if any messages have been written under the `pushid`.

Then you retreive the data from the database using: `var valueObject = event.data.val();`.

And in the `notification{..}`  you can use `valueObject.title` which will be the topic name, thus when recieving a notification, the topic name will be in the title of the notification and thats how you can know what topic it is.

For more info check https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Comment: Well, first I'm not using JS (but id does not matter), second, I was looking for some solution that does not require to modify request, I was hoping there is some way to retrieve `to` field, which is already there. Also, I don't want to include topic name in title, better to place it in `data`

Comment: what are u using in the backend then?

Comment: This does not matter actually, most important is that backend just performs POST request with json data as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: yes as mentioned in my answer, it is posting the data in the database and sending the notification for android phones.. The reason i added topic name as title is for the user to know from what subject he is recieving this notification

Comment: End user should not know from what subject topic is added. Title ≠ subject. Better to add additional data to `data` structure, but it's not what am I asking for